# OS X Server Profile Manager port forwarding?

Tags: network, macos, osx-server, dns

I am setting up a MDM server on OS X Server.  This is just a personal project, so I am hosting off of my iMac running Yosemite and OS X Server.  I have configured port forwarding and DNS records so that my domain can access the iMac.  The problem is that ports 80 and 443 are unavailable (due to my ISP), and I need to forward them.  I can either do domain.com:1234, or somehow tell the domain to point to port "1234" (for example?)

If I do the first option, I'll need to tell OS X Server that somehow...but I can't find the option.  Is there a way to accomplish that, or to "point" the domain to a specific port by default?  Thanks!

Comment: I would check your port-forwarding rules again. Having port 80 blocked would give you no Internet access. Also check your DNS versus your public IP, as well as the TTL of your DNS entry. The TTL may be set too high and your requests are dying because the address hasn't propagated through the DNS servers.

Comment: @douggro sorry I meant port 80 _incoming_.  I had set up a port forwarding (just testing) from public port 1234 to internal port 80.  When I went to http://example.com:1234, it worked fine.  The problem is that I can't specify a port in OS X server, so profiles, etc are returning an error.  So I'd either have to figure out how to specify an alternative HTTP port in OS X, or set the default port in DNS, if possible.